# AND conditions in Doctrine

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, conditional-statements

I'm working with Doctrine 2 and I came up with the situation in which I want to do some queries only among a few type of users.

```
  Type   Status  Active
 UserA   0       0
 UserB   0       1
 UserC   1       1
 UserD   1       0
```

All the queries I wanna do involves User A, User C and User D. One example is this next query:

```
    public function countMonth(){
      $date = new \Datetime('now');
      $newDate = $date->format('Y-m');
      $this->qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
      $this->qb->select('count(u) as cant')
         ->from('models\User', 'u')
         ->where('u.creation_date like ?1')
         ->andWhere('u.status <> 0 AND u.active <> 1'); //users B
      $this->qb->setParameter(1,"$newDate%");
      $query = $this->qb->getQuery();
      return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
```

I want to know how to do a query that throws me back all users but user B. Because the one that I wrote just gives me the usersD.

I know I can do this in order to get all users but usersB, but It kind of annoys me to write two lines of code to ask for this. Is there a more simplified way?

```
public function countMonth(){
    $orX = $this->qb->expr()->orX();
    $andX = $this->qb->expr()->andX();          
    $date = new \Datetime('now');
    $newDate = $date->format('Y-m');
    $this->qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $this->qb->select('count(u) as cant')
        ->from('models\User', 'u');
    $andX->add('u.creation_date like ?1');
    $orX->add('u.status = 1 AND u.active = 1 OR u.active = 0'); 
    $orX->add('u.status = 0 AND u.active = 0');
    $andX->add($orX);
    $this->qb->add('where', $andX);
    $this->qb->setParameter(1,"$newDate%");
    $query = $this->qb->getQuery();
    return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use OR

```
'u.status <> 0 OR u.active <> 1'
```

- The logic output for `'u.status <> 0 AND u.active <> 1'` is **true** for **userD only** beacuse both arguments must be true when using **AND** logical operator.
- For **userA** u.status <> 0 fails this condition.
- For **userC** u.active <> 1 fails this condition.

Now, using **OR** you get the following:

- For **userA**: `u.status <> 0` is true and `u.active <> 1` is false, **one is true**, pass
- For **userB**: `u.status <> 0` is false and `u.active <> 1` is false, **both false**, fails
- For **userC**: `u.status <> 0` is true and `u.active <> 1` is true, **both true**, pass
- For **userD**: `u.status <> 0` is false and `u.active <> 1` is true, **one is true**, pass

This way, all rows but **userB** passes the condition.

--------- EDIT -----------

Check this out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3174/1/0